# How to find a specific folder in its super directory of a given path using java

Tags: java, file, search, directory

- How to find a specific folder in its super directory of a given path using java?
- For Example I need to find a folder which holds name as : "Incoming" in the given path as : D:\test\28-4-2016\spr\5526283_1\ItemFile\1446026507776_1\ftp\content-providers\spr-e\data\incoming\EHPP-17-2-2015\EHPP-17-2-2015
- I need to find the folder and its path.
- My present code not finding the folder.
- Can anyone help me to Achieve This?

-------------------Code snippet starts--------------------------
      public static void find()
      {

```
        File dir = new File("D:\\test\\28-4-2016\\apa\\5346560_1 
  \\ItemFile\\1444799103007_1\\ftp\\content-providers\\apa-e\\data
  \\incoming\\CBS_v47i4");
    findDirectory(dir);
  }
   private static void findDirectory(File parentDirectory) {
    if(foundFolder) {
        return;
    }
    File[] files = parentDirectory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (file.getName().equals("incoming")) {
            foundFolder = true;
            System.out.println("Incoming Folder found : ");
            System.out.println("Incoming filder path : 
  "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Parent path :  " +file.getParent());
            break;
        }
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
           findDirectory(file);
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are getting? any exception or wrong output?

Comment: Sorry I have updated in my question.The folder "Incoming" will contain in the super directory of a given path.

Comment: @ Blip : Kind help me to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you sir,can you please help me to guide me how to retrieve the string upto Incoming.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `findDirectory` method as follows

```
public static void find() {
    File dir = new File(
            "D:\\test\\28-4-2016\\apa\\5346560_1\\ItemFile\\1444799103007_1\\ftp\\content-providers\\apa-e\\data\\incoming\\CBS_v47i4");
    foundFolder = findDirectory(dir);
}

private static boolean findDirectory(File parentDirectory) {
    System.out.println(parentDirectory.getPath());
    File[] files = parentDirectory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isFile()) {

            if (file.getName().equals("incoming")) {

                System.out.println("Incoming Folder found : ");
                System.out.println("Incoming filder path : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Parent path :  " + file.getParent());
                return true;
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                return findDir(file);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Incoming Folder not found : ");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in your example and the hard-coded path? Also, use Path.pathSeperator() rather than double splash. I would suggest you recursively, navigate to sub-folders and output all files and directories to debug.